# Can't establish connection to Web Server using rosbridge

Tags: websocket, ros

I have created a simple HTML page to control the movement of a simulated Gazebo Turtlebot using `roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch` following this tutorial.

However, in the Web Console of the HTML page (F12) it shows the error "Firefox cant establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:9090/." I am using the default rosbridge for the websocket(9090). In the Terminal I am also receiving the errors:

[-] failing WebSocket opening handshake ('WebSocket connection denied: origin 'null' not allowed')

[-] dropping connection to peer tcp4:127.0.0.1:41290 with abort=False: WebSocket connection denied: origin 'null' not allowed.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you tried with python -m SimpleHTTPServer serving your html/javascript file?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to do that, how would I be able to connect the SimpleHTTPServer to the HTML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have followed the ROS tutorial and have created an HTML file as shown in [Ros Bridge tutorial](https://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs/Tutorials/BasicRosFunctionality) then you have to run:

- `runcore`
- `rosrun rospy_tutorials add_two_ints_server`
- `roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch`

Now that you have these up and running, you need to serve the html/javascript file (e.g. *simple.html*) and start the services etc. For example, you can serve the *simple.html* by using a [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html), see below an example (e.g. *simplehttpserver_test.py*):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

class MyRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):    
    def do_GET(self):    
        if self.path == '/':
            self.path = '/simple.html'            
        return SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)        

Handler = MyRequestHandler
server = SocketServer.TCPServer(('127.0.0.1', 9089), Handler)    
server.serve_forever()
```

Once you run the *simplehttpserver_test.py* you can open the browser on *127.0.0.1:9089* and you should be able to have it working.

Note that [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) serves files from the current directory and below, directly mapping the directory structure to HTTP requests, which means that the *simple.html* should be in the same (or below) directory as the *simplehttpserver_test.py*. Last, the port for the *simplehttpserver_test.py* should differ from the one used for the *Rosbridge WebSocket server* (e.g. default is 9090).

Comment: Hello, this method works, thank you! But is there a way that I could do this without having to use SimpleHTTPServer like the [ROSBridge tutorial?](https://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs/Tutorials/BasicRosFunctionality) As I'm still having the original issue in the question.